# having difficult in debugging some functions where the author mainly did axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reading a codebase where I see this way of writing code. I am having difficulty in introducing console logs.

I would like to do a console log for the entire URL that is being sent and also the response and error.

```
 const fetchSportsFanDetails = (sportsFanId, authToken) =>
  axios
    .get(`${API.BASE_URL}SportsFans/${sportsFanId}/profile`, {
      headers: {
        ...getAuthHeaderWithContentType(authToken, "JSON")
      }
    })
    .then(resp => (resp && resp.data ? resp.data : null));
```

I am having difficulty in debugging this piece of written code. Can anyone please assist me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow. The issue is that the {} of the function are omited since it does one line, which makes it hard to introduce new lines without adding it first.

```
 const fetchSportsFanDetails = (sportsFanId, authToken) => {
    let url = `${API.BASE_URL}SportsFans/${sportsFanId}/profile`;
    console.log(`url: ${url}`)
    axios
    .get(url, {
      headers: {
        ...getAuthHeaderWithContentType(authToken, "JSON")
      }
    })
    .then(resp => (resp && resp.data ? resp.data : null));
   }
```

edit for response, replace the .then with
 `.then(resp => {console.log(resp); (resp && resp.data ? resp.data : null)});`

Basically you are working with arrow functions https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/

Comment: Yeah . It helped .Would like to debug response too .Should I do something similar .

Comment: Yep. Edited answer with example